# How do i create .o file?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Here is a part of  code written in eclipse.

I am making a GUI for a compiler and this is the action performed when a compile button is pressed.

```
File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    try {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
            textContent.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String filepath = file.getPath();
        String filepath2 = filepath.substring(0, filepath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
        System.out.println(filepath);
        System.out.println(filepath2);
        String name = file.getName();
        String name2 = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf("."));
         String folder = filepath2+"\\";
    String o = folder+name2+".o";
         System.out.println(o);
        ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder();
          try {
              pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "arm-none-eabi-gcc "+"-c "+"-march=armv8-a "+"-g "  + "\"" + filepath2 + "\\" +name + "\"" + " -o \""+ name2+"\"");  
              pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "arm-none-eabi-g++ "+"-c "+"-march=armv8-a "+"-g "  + "\"" + filepath2 + "\\" +name + "\"" + " -o \""+ name2+"\"");   
            pb.directory(new File(filepath2));
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
            int x = p.exitValue();

            if (x == 0) {   
                area.setForeground(red);
                area.setText("            == 0 error.. Compilation Finished");
            } else {

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                //BufferedWriter rm=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

                String out;
                area.setText("");
                while ((out = r.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    area.setForeground(RED);
                    area.append(out + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
```

Output:

When I compile the program (test.cpp), it is simply creating a test file, and I want the output to be test.
[image: output]

Console:

In fact, it shows in the console that it has created a test.o file
[image: console]

Comment: The `name2` variable that you're using in the command doesn't end with ".o" is just the original file's name without the extension.

Comment: but i have mentioned it here "String o = folder+name2+".o";" will this not work?

Comment: You're not using the `o` variable in the command, you're using `name2`.

Comment: i have created another set of same program but with .exe                               String exe = folder+name2+".exe";
                 System.out.println(exe);
          
                ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder();
                  try {
                   pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "gcc " + "\"" + filepath2 + "\\" + name + "\"" + " -o \"" + name2+"\"");
                      
                      
                      pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "g++ " + "\"" + filepath2 + "\\" + name + "\"" + " -o \"" + name2+"\"");

Comment: and this is giving me correct file

Comment: Wait a minute: Is this all about the fact that the file explorer shows this as `test`, and not as `test.o`? If so, this is just a configuration setting of the file explorer. If not ... sorry, maybe I misunderstood this...